# Validate numeric value but exclude hex or sci notation

Tags: php, regex, validation, hex, preg-match

I used to rely on `is_numeric()` for making sure data passed from users is numeric.  I recently discovered that users can also pass data `0xFF` (hexdec = 255).

I'd like to disallow anything that is not a whole number (and not a hex representation).

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
$i_haxors_u = $_GET['id'];

$regex = '/[0-9]*/';
if (!empty($i_haxors_u) && !preg_match($regex, $i_haxors_u))
 {
   echo '<p>Invalid $i_haxors_u ' . strip_tags($i_haxors_u);
 } else { 
   echo '<p>$i_haxors_u is numeric... maybe.';
 }
```

This is still giving values like `0xFF` a pass.  How do I allow non-hex numbers only?

---

UPDATE Nov 12 2014.

Note that the [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26808890/721073) works fine for data passed via GET, but will not work if a variable is set to a hex value.

```
$x = 0xFF;
if (is_numeric($x))
{
    echo "<p>$x is a number.";
} else {
    echo "<p>$x is not a number.";
}

if (preg_match('/^[\d]+$/',$x))
{
    echo "<p>$x is a number.";
} else {
    echo "<p>$x is not a number.";
}

$x = '0xFF';
if (is_numeric($x))
{
    echo "<p>$x is a number.";
} else {
    echo "<p>$x is not a number.";
}

if (preg_match('/^[\d]+$/',$x))
{
    echo "<p>$x is a number.";
} else {
    echo "<p>$x is not a number.";
}
```

Prints

```
255 is a number.

255 is a number.

0xFF is a number.

0xFF is not a number.
```

Comment: There is actually 2 conditions. Is the string empty, is it valid digits. `if (empty($v){'empty'}else{ if (!preg_match(/\D/,$v){'alldigits'}else{'atleast1non-digit'} }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use match non-digit in your regex: $regex = '/\D/';
assume failure and pass when confirming that no non-digits are present in the input.

following code succeeds on id =7, give fail on id = 7.2, 7.2x, ffff, 0xff, -1

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

//assuming failure:
$valid = false;

if (!preg_match('/\D/',$id)) { $valid = true; } //fail if containing non-digit


if ($valid) {
echo "$id provided is valid";
}
else {
echo "$id provided is not valid";
}
```

Comment: I think it's a good idea. But when I code, I try not to test what should not be the solution, it is easier to remember later what should be the solution ;-)

Comment: +1 This is the best solution. @Croises , its better to positively match what you are looking for. `preg_match('/\D/',$id)`, you have found the culprit.

Comment: @Croises Not assuming valid input is critical for security and data sanitization tasks.  Assuming success leaves you wide open.  Size is as simple as adding in && ($id > $minSize).  Sign can be ignored by altering the regex. Comment the code to explain each condition.  Addtional if statements can valid special cases.

Comment: See update to question for interesting note about preg_match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use anchors and use `+` quantifier to only allow integers:

```
$regex = '/^\d+$/';
```

Using `+` quantifier will also let you take out `!empty($i_haxors_u)` condition since `\d+` will enforce 1 or more digits.

Answer (score 1):

It's just because you have to test all the number:

```
$regex = '/^[0-9]+$/';
```

no need to test empty with +